# Use arduino library in nanoFramework?

Tags: nanoframework

is it somehow possible to use an arduino library in nanoFramework? I really want to use nanoFramework but for this I need the OneWire library from arduino due to actually it is not possible to define the pin number in one wire controller in nanoFramework. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to do that is to use the Interop features of .NET #nanoFramework.
See the blog post with the explanations [here](https://jsimoesblog.wordpress.com/2018/06/19/interop-in-net-nanoframework/).